# Angular Chart JS - Tooltip appears on labels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I am working with Angular Chart JS Library and using Bar and Line Charts. Also i have a tooltip for all the datapoints.

Strangely the tooltip in the line chart is also working, when i hover over the labels (in my example: ["J","F","M", "A", "M", "J", "J"]). But in the bar chart the Tooltip only appears when I hover over the bars.

How can I add this function also to the bar chart that the tooltip is working, when I hover over the labels ?

You can see the difference in my Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/WQCvm4VU0M6oz6b4E5GS?p=preview

```
 <div>
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules" ng-style="{'background-color': module.background, 'color': module.fontcolor, 'border': module.border}">
        <div class=""><canvas id="base" class="chart chart-base" widht="" chart-type="module.type" chart-data="module.data" chart-labels="module.labels" chart-series="module.series" chart-colours="module.colors" chart-options="module.options"></canvas></div>              
      </li>
</ul>
```